# Pagination in laravel only brings results from a more advanced page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a search page where I have some specific filters and I page 60 data per page, the problem is that when I put a more specific filter, it doesn't bring anything on the first page, but if I navigate to page 5, for For example, results start to appear, how do I make this older data that appears further on the pages appear on the first pages that have no results?

I'm using laravel's paginate, here's a piece of code below. I'm also including how I send the json.

```php
$articles = $articles->orderBy('nc33_content.publish_up', 'desc')->orderBy('nc33_content.modified', 'desc')
          ->groupBy('nc33_content.id')->paginate(60);

if (count($articles) == 0) {
      $return = ["status"  => [['active' => 0, "msg" => "No data!"]]];
    } else {
      $return = ["status"  => [['active' => 1, "msg" => "OK!"]], "articles" => $articles];
    }

    return response()->json($retorno);
```

Comment: Can you show us the filters? You need to isolate which filters are causing the empty result set on page 1. We can't really see what's causing the issue given the code you've shown us.